# Type Error: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, typeerror

```
for x in values:
    x = header.index["NoExamples*NoFeatures"]
    print (x)
```

when i wrote this codes there is a error second row.

`"TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable"`.

could you help me about that?

Comment: what is header in this? and why you assigning that again to x? which is the object of values.

Comment: seems like `header.index` is a function

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: If `header` is either a string or a list, you need to use parentheses `()` and not brackets `[]` to get the index.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, `header` is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) (e.g. a `list`) and `index` is the builtin method to find the first occurrence of an element. The problem is that you are trying to call the method with square brackets (`[]`), which are Python syntax for indexing, instead of parentheses. The right syntax should be:

```
x = header.index("NoExamples*NoFeatures")
```

Which will give you the index of the first occurence of the string `"NoExamples*NoFeatures"` in the sequence `header`.